# Symfony2/ get variable from subdomaine and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I using Symfony2.

What would be the best practice to get a variable from URL. I am using subdomain to get the city.
Ex: paris.website.com

> how do I get Paris as variable.
>   I believe I need to play with Kernel and htaccess, but I haven't figured out how.

Thanks if you can put me on right tracks about that.

Cheers,

Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) of Symfony. One of the basis components of Symfony is the [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) that provides exactly what you need :

www.mysite.com/paris/

Using the subdomain is not the solution, but you can play with .htaccess to rewrite subdomain paris.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/paris (if web server allows it) after having configured your route in Symfony.